# R: unable to download file

Tags: r, http, httprequest

I wan to download a file using the following request:

```
request <- 'http://earthserver.ecmwf.int/rasdaman/ows?service=WCS&version=2.0.1&request=ProcessCoverages&query=for c in (geff_fire_weather_index) return encode(c[Lat(35:47),Long(6:18),ansi("2015-01-01T00:00":"2015-12-31T00:00")],"netcdf")'

download.file(url = request, destfile = "rea.nc")
```

If I run this using the browser it works no problem but in R it fails with the following error message:

```
downloaded 0 bytes

Error in download.file(url = request2, destfile = "rea.nc") : 
cannot download all files
In addition: Warning message:
In download.file(url = request2, destfile = "rea.nc") :
URL 'http://earthserver.ecmwf.int/rasdaman/ows?service=WCS&version=2.0.1&request=ProcessCoverages&query=for c in (geff_fire_weather_index) return encode(c[Lat(35:47),Long(6:18),ansi("2015-01-01T00:00":"2015-12-31T00:00")],"netcdf")': status was 'Couldn't connect to server'
```

Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: Working as intended for me. Are you behind a proxy?

Comment: Yes, I'm behind a proxy. How can I adapt the download request to take into account the proxy settings?

Comment: I set the http_proxy in this way Sys.setenv(http_proxy="http://myproxy:myport/") but still no luck

Comment: use the `httr` package? like `httr::set_config(httr::use_proxy(url="myproxy.com", port=8080))`

Comment: still not working, this time I get HTTP status was '0 (null)'